# FPDF Text with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create an A4 sized PDF, I can add text/images and this is working fine.  I have a dynamically generated string which contains some HTML tags (BR etc) and was wondering how I can have that output onto the PDF as opposed to literally printing the tags out.

```
$centre = urldecode($row_CertDetails['centre_name']);

$pdf->Text(10, 110, $centre);
```

I've seen on some forums people mentioning `WriteHTML`, however my version of FPDF doesn't seem to include that.

Is it an add-on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an Add-On:

> **Write HTML**
>
> Author: Clément Lavoillotte
> License: FPDF
>
> This is an enhancement of the `WriteHTML()` method from tutorial 6. Supported tags are: ...

Please see [Write HTML FPDF Script #42](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) which I think is the latest version, but feel free to [browse the FPDF scripts/Add-Ons](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/).

Comment: Thanks, I've saved the script as `html2pdf.php`, removed the reference to `require_once("fpdf.php")` as it's already included on my parent page, and added `required_once('html2pdf.php')`.  When I call WriteHTML($variable) the PDF doesn't try and render.

Comment: I'd say that is a different question. SO works best to keep things a bit apart. You might want to ask your next question providing the code-example what you did so far. Please also see that the link above comes with an example. First try to get the example working verbatim before you try with your own code. That will show you if you understood how it *generally* works before adapting.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention this is running with FPDI as well, so there could be some intervention there to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it anyway.

Because I'm also using FPDI, what I did was extract the contents of the class in http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php and put it inside the `FPDI.php` file.