# html tags issue in pdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have texts

```
  $text1 =  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  $text2 =  <p>7<sup>2</sup></p>
  $text3 =  <b>This is bold</b>
```

I have to display these texts as pdf. I tried like this:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,$num.". ".$text1, 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,$num.". ".$text2, 0, 1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,$num.". ".$text3, 0, 1);
```

The result is

```
 <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 <p>7<sup>2</sup></p>
 <b>This is bold</b>
```

But I the expected result is:

This is a paragraph

7<sup>2</sup>

**This is bold**

How can I do this? Please help me..

I am using **fpdf** for pdf generation.

Comment: Maybe you don't have addon? More about it:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15272315/4015178

Comment: FPDF does not support `HTML`. You should use a Addon like [PDF_HTML](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/41/).

Comment: BTW: You forgot the quotes. Use `$text1 =  '<p>This is a paragraph</p>';` instead of `$text1 =  <p>This is a paragraph</p>`

Comment: I recommend an alternative library sush as [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) or [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Comment: Check may be it help you, http://www.fpdf.org/~~V/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=27295&t=27271

Comment: you can use tcpdf for create pdf which support for writeHTML and similar with fpdf

Answer (score 0):

there is solution given for you problem in FPDF form

```
if (in_array( strtoupper($val['tag']) , array('SUP','SUB'))) { 
// use the SetStyle-function to define Sub/Sub properties 
$bakY = $this->y; 
$bakX = $this->x; 
if (strtoupper($val['tag'])=="SUP") 
$this->SetY($bakY-1); 
else 
$this->SetY($bakY+1); 
$this->SetX($bakX); 
} 

if (in_array( strtoupper($val['tag']) , array('SUP','SUB'))) { 
$bakX = $this->x; 
$this->SetY($bakY); 
$this->SetX($bakX); 
}
```

This code belongs to FPDF form. Hope this will help you out.